# How to pass an entity stored in session to new entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity

I store an entity in session:

```
$equipoActividad = new EquiposActividades();
$equipoActividad->setEquipoControl($equipoControlExiste);
$actividadObj=$em->getRepository('AgcManagerBundle:Actividad')->findOneBy(array('idActividad'=>$idActividad));
$equipoActividad->setActividad($actividadObj);
$equipoActividad->setIdUsuario($user->getIdUser());
$tipoTransmision = new TipoTransmision();
$tipoTransmision->setIdTipoTransmision(0);
$protocolo = new Protocolo();
$protocolo->setIdProtocolo(0);
$equipoActividad->setTipoTransmision($tipoTransmision);
$equipoActividad->setProtocolo($protocolo);
$request->getSession()->set("equipoActividad", $equipoActividad);
```

After I store this entity into a new entity:

```
$equipoActividad = new EquiposActividades();
$equipoActividad = $request->getSession()->get("equipoActividad");
```

This is the error:

> Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?

UPDATE:

```
$equipoActividad = $request->getSession()->get("equipoActividad");
$equipoActividad = $em->merge($equipoActividad);
/* The next code is this*/
$formulario = $this->createForm(new EquipoActividadType(array('idUsuario' => $user->getIdUser())), $equipoActividad);          
$formulario->handleRequest($request);
```

ERROR:

```
Entity was not found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$equipoActividad = $request->getSession()->get("equipoActividad");
```

then

```
$em->merge($equipoActividad);
```

All entities that will be handle by doctrine need to be managed. Session object aren't anymore. So you don't need to create a brand-new one as with `merge()` entity manager takes care for you to manage again that entity and from that time on, you can use it like you've fetched from db.

If you want to know more about, read http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/entities-in-session.html

---

## EDIT

Error here is due to your object status: in fact you didn't persisted it before session store (merge need the entity to be already persisted and flushed to db). You can either persist/flush it before storing in session or after it, when you use session retrieval facility.

BTW you can also not persist it if you don't need to :)

Comment: @IvanJavierBarrancoGavilan: please, update your question if you want to provide more details, don't put them in here

Comment: The problem is that there must persisting it to fill in the second form is the one I show you, if the user cancels the assistant does not save changes.

Comment: I can not copy the object and then copy it?

Comment: @IvanJavierBarrancoGavilan: why do you need to copy the object? Simply load all fields that you need, put object in session, make your controls and persist all you need.